# Check exit code of an unrelated process

Tags: c, linux, process, pid, exit-code

I want to check the exit code of a foreground process using C code running on linux. As I understand, `wait()` and `waitpid()` are useful for child processes, but in my case, it is a foreign process. I am able to read information from /proc/<pid>/stat for that process while it is active, but as the process closes, reading from /proc/<pid>/ becomes problematic and I didn't find any information relating to exit code.

Other things I've tried:

popen() some bash commands. `echo $?` always returned 0, even when process of interest exited with an error code. I am not sure it targeted the process of interest. Another bash command I tried to call, was `wait <pid>` but this command returned immediately, while the process was still running.

Comment: One other idea I had in mind, was to write exit value to a file before exit, and then read that from my program. This solution is a bit clumsy, and I wonder if there is something else I could use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the foreground process' code, you can send a message via a message queue or even a socket (e.g. udp multicast) - and that will make the solution more general (your c program can run on a different machine).

Another option is to use a loggging service (syslog or something like that). it has some
useful interfaces that enable processes to log their exit codes.

Comment: I do have access to foreground process' code. I think message queue solution fits for my case. Thank you.